# Switch inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Just can't figure out what is wrong. In activity, the code below works like a charm. But when i use it inside a fragment, app is crashing with this error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Here is the code

```
public class design extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_design, container, false);
    Switch night_mode_always = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.sNight);

    night_mode_always.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

As soon the setOnCheckedChangeListener is called, app crashes...I tried different ways to implement activity, context, tried with OnClick...But i could figure out how to do it with switch. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.testapp, PID: 25299
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.testapp.settings.design$1
com.test.testapp.settings.design.onCreateView(design.java:32)
```

Comment: Put your log & exception to find what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the design library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

I'm also not sure what type of Fragment you are using. Is it a support library Fragment? If it is, you can use the  appcompat version of the switch:

http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-switch-button-example/

The switch looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="SwitchCompat (SDK v7+)"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    app:showText="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks, but not worked. I am already using design library. And i use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;. I changed the Switch, to SwitchCompat, but it keep on crashing on the same place.